# Adding sequential row to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel file (.xlsx) that is generated every day and gives a breakdown of statistics from the previous day, for each hour.  Example:

As you can see, there was no Data recorded for hours 2 and 4.  But on another day, there could be Data for every row for hours 0-23.

My end goal is to have a Master spreadsheet where Column A has a row for each Hour (0-23), then a column with the date as the header and the Data populated in the correct hour row below, and if there was no data for that hour, enter 0 or leave it blank.

I can merge the Excel files, but my question I can't quite seem to get is: before I merge the files, how can I have Excel insert the appropriate number of rows when data is empty?  Is it something a Powershell script can do, or an Excel Template that I can apply to the file before merging?

I can merge Excel files all day long and add the expected columns.  But I'm struggling with adding in rows when data is missing.

EDIT:
Here is the input from Day 1

| Hour | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 |
| 1 | 9876 |
| 3 | 4567 |
| 5 | 2258 |

Here is the input from Day 2

| Hour | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 654 |
| 2 | 3697 |
| 3 | 7852 |
| 4 | 6548 |

And here is what I would expect the output to be:

| Hour | Day 1 | Day 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | 654 |
| 1 | 9876 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 3697 |
| 3 | 4567 | 7852 |
| 4 | 0 | 6548 |
| 5 | 2258 | 0 |

Comment: You have to first create a row for each hour/day.  Then merge in data.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post to try and make it more clear.  So for the first example, I need to insert a row for hours 2 and 4, and the Data on the left can be blank or zero.  But how do I automate that so that I receive a spreadsheet, it adds the rows that are not included?

Comment: Do not insert.  First create the blank worksheet with just the hours 1 to 24.  Then merge.  Much simpler.

Comment: @bgorton would you put the input and expected output (mainly this one) in Table Markdown format? You can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). To avoid any guessing about the expected output you are looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I edited my original post using this extremely helpful table generator!  Thank you!

Comment: How are you merging the spreadsheets at the moment? Manually, or with a script? Can you add any code you’ve already written into your original question…

Comment: At the moment I'm doing a weird VLOOKUP to compare the two spreadsheets, and output the values.  This works, but is a manual process and I have two spreadsheets per server, and 50+ servers.  Automating the process seems to be the best option.